# Pattern matching F# type in a C# code

Tags: c#, f#, interop

Suppose there is a `F#` definitions:

```ml
type Either<'a,'b> = | Left of 'a | Right of 'b

let f (i : int) : Either<int, string> =
    if i > 0
        then Left i
        else Right "nothing"
```

Function `f` is used in `C#` code:

```cs
var a = Library.f(5);
```

How the result value `a` could be pattern matched for data constructors? Something like:

```cs
/*
(if a is Left x)
    do something with x
(if a is Right y)
    do something with y
*/
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Using F# discriminated unions from C# is a bit inelegant, because of how they are compiled.

I think the best approach is to define some members (on the F# side) that will simplify using the types from C#. There are multiple options, but the one I prefer is to define `TryLeft` and `TryRight` methods that behave similarly to `Int32.TryParse` (and so they should be familiar to C# developers using your F# API):

```ml
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

type Either<'a,'b> = 
  | Left of 'a 
  | Right of 'b
  member x.TryLeft([<Out>] a:byref<'a>) =
    match x with Left v -> a <- v; true | _ -> false
  member x.TryRight([<Out>] b:byref<'b>) =
    match x with Right v -> b <- v; true | _ -> false
```

Then you can use the type from C# as follows:

```
int a;
string s;
if (v.TryLeft(out a)) Console.WriteLine("Number: {0}", a);
else if (v.TryRight(out s)) Console.WriteLine("String: {0}", s);
```

You lose some of the F# safety by doing this, but that's expected in a language without pattern matching. But the good thing is that anybody familiar with .NET should be able to use the API implemented in F#.

Another alternative would be to define member `Match` that takes `Func<'a>` and `Func<'b>` delegates and invokes the right delegate with the value carried by left/right case. This is a bit nicer from the functional perspective, but it might be less obvious to C# callers.

Answer (score 6):

I'd define a `Match` member taking the delegates to execute in each scenario.  In F# you'd do it like this (but you could do something equivalent in a C# extension method, if desired):

```ml
type Either<'a,'b> = | Left of 'a | Right of 'b
with
    member this.Match<'t>(ifLeft:System.Func<'a,'t>, ifRight:System.Func<'b,'t>) =
        match this with
        | Left a -> ifLeft.Invoke a
        | Right b -> ifRight.Invoke b
```

Now you should be able to do something like this in C#:

```cs
var result = a.Match(ifLeft: x => x + 1, ifRight: y => 2 * y);
```

Comment: there are some restrictions for that solution. Like, you cannot do something like `a.Match(ifLeft: x => x + 1, ifRight: _ => return null);`

Answer (score 1):

From the [3.0 spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597545):

> 8.5.4     Compiled Form of Union Types for Use from Other CLI Languages
>
> A compiled union type U has:
>
> 1. One CLI static getter property U.C for each null union case C. This property gets a singleton object that represents each such case.
> 2. One CLI nested type U.C for each non-null union case C. This type has instance properties Item1, Item2.... for each field of the union
>      case, or a single instance property Item if there is only one field.
>      However, a compiled union type that has only one case does not have a
>      nested type. Instead, the union type itself plays the role of the case
>      type.
> 3. One CLI static method U.NewC for each non-null union case C. This method constructs an object for that case.
> 4. One CLI instance property U.IsC for each case C. This property returns true or false for the case.
> 5. One CLI instance property U.Tag for each case C. This property fetches or computes an integer tag corresponding to the case.
> 6. If U has more than one case, it has one CLI nested type U.Tags. The U.Tags typecontains one integer literal for each case, in increasing
>      order starting from zero.
> 7. A compiled union type has the methods that are required to implement its auto-generated interfaces, in addition to any
>      user-defined properties or methods.
>
> These methods and properties may not be used directly from F#.
>   However, these types have user-facing List.Empty, List.Cons,
>   Option.None, and Option.Some properties and/or methods.
>
> A compiled union type may not be used as a base type in another CLI
>   language, because it has at least one assembly-private constructor and
>   no public constructors.

If you can't change the F# api, using points 2 and 4 above you could do it something like this:

C#

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        PrintToConsole("5");
        PrintToConsole("test");
    }

    static void PrintToConsole(string value)
    {
        var result = test.getResult(value);
        if (result.IsIntValue) Console.WriteLine("Is Int: " + ((test.DUForCSharp.IntValue)result).Item);
        else Console.WriteLine("Is Not Int: " + ((test.DUForCSharp.StringValue)result).Item);
    }
}
```

F#

```
namespace Library1

module test =

    open System

    type DUForCSharp =
    | IntValue of int
    | StringValue of string

    let getResult x =
        match Int32.TryParse x with
        | true, value -> IntValue(value)
        | _ -> StringValue(x)
```

This solution is convenient in that it also handles tuple DU cases by creating a new property for each item in the tuple.